# Rails 5 Controller cannot get model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Having trouble with a form in a nested controller on the 'new' action.  In this nested controller, I am trying to use a model called 'Company'.  The exact error message is:

```
NoMethodError in Admin::Companies#new

Showing /app/views/admin/companies/new.html.erb where line #4 raised:

undefined method `companies_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f2d89571cb0>:0x007f2d899f5e08>

Did you mean?  compute_asset_path

Line 4: <%= simple_form_for(@company) do |f| %>
```

Why is it asking about the path when I am trying to use the model?

Here is my controller:

```
class Admin::CompaniesController < AdminsController
  def new
    @company = Company.new
  end

  def create
    @company = Company.new(company_params)

    if @company.save
      redirect_to admin_index_path
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Error - Please try again"
      render :new
    end
  end
end

private

def company_params
  params.require(:company).permit(:name, :location)
end
```

My routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :admin do
    resources :companies
  end

  resources :admins

  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations' }

  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

**Note: Using Rails 5.1

Can post more info if needed.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to this.  Apparently, when using a nested controller you have to include the namespace in the form.

Example that worked:

```
<%= simple_form_for ([:admin, @company]) do |f| %>
```

Compared to original format that didn't work:

```
<%= simple_form_for @company do |f| %>
```